# Xcode 6.1 - Custom font doesn't show for attributed text on label

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts

I just discovered the `Attributed` text option in Xcode where I can change all my text's attributes. Problem is, the custom font I added to my project doesn't show up in the list. It shows up fine when the text option is set to `Plain`.

How can I make my custom font appear in the font list for `Attributed`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known bug on Xcode: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5117089870249984

Comment: An alternative way to make it work while the rdar isn't closed is installing the font in your system.